# Difference between Center and Expanded in this case?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I wanted everything after AppBar centered. However it is not centered.
This is what my code looks like. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me why my current code is not centering the Login to the Password items.

This is what my current layout looks like

[image]

This is my code

```
class MyScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // Material is a conceptual piece of paper on which the UI appears.
        return new Material(
            // Column is a vertical, linear layout.

            child: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>
                    [
                        new MyAppBar(
                            title: new Text('Example title', style: Theme
                                    .of(context)
                                    .primaryTextTheme
                                    .title),
                            ),

                        new Center(
                            child: new Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                        new Text("Login"),

                                        new TextField(
                                                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                                        border: new OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: '---')),

                                        new Text("Password"),

                                        new TextField(
                                                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                                        border: new OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: '---')),

                                    ]),
                            )


                    ]
                    ));
    }
}
```

I would like it to look like this

[image]

I know I can achieve that look replacing center with expanded. Why does that work ? What is the difference between the two. Can anyone please clarify what Expanded really does ?

Comment: It looks centered to me.

Comment: I just updated the post. I would like the login till Password widgets centered vertically

Answer (score 0):

Using expanded forces the child to take up available space. [Read more here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

Comment: nope in that case appbar will shift to the center as well

Comment: @MistyD true. I didn't see that.

Comment: @MistyD I just modified my answer. Expanded works because unlike Center it takes up the remaining available parent space.

Comment: This still doesnt answer the question. In that case why do i get this look if I add ` mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,` to my main column.Thanks for trying anyways